How is this still in the scope?
So, my question involves the following code I saw as the answer to a project on Codecademy, called "Abruptly Goblins!"
def find_best_night(availability_table):
    best_availability = 0
    for day, availability in availability_table.items():
        if availability > best_availability:
            best_night = day
            best_availability = availability
    return best_night

As titled, my question is about scope. I see that best_night is created to equal the day, which is fine, but shouldn't it go away after the iteration is complete? I mean, I realize it doesn't, as it is returned at the end of the call, but I was under the impression this would have to have been declared differently in order to be passed this way. Would anyone be able to shine some light on this a bit for me?

Python doesn't have block scope - function locals are local to the entire function.

You're right to question this code, but the issue isn't scope related (Python scoping rules do not follow block scoping used by many other languages). The real issue here, is that best_night is conditionally assigned. This code has a possible UnboundLocalError if the conditional logic is not called (e.g. the table is empty or all availability values are less than zero) and return best_night is called without it ever being locally assigned.
